# Updating Rank in table

Tags: php, mysql

This code create's rank on the fly and set's them accordingly..
Now the question is how do I update the Rank values in the table, without duplicating?

Help me Please!
Thanks ...

```
SELECT TeamID,
       TeamName,
       TeamLeader,
       TeamEmail,
       TeamWins,
       TeamLoss,
       TeamPoints,
       TeamRank
       FROM
          (
             SELECT TeamID,
                    TeamName,
                    TeamLeader,
                    TeamEmail,
                    TeamWins,
                    TeamLoss,
                    TeamPoints,
                    @Rank := @Rank + 1 AS TeamRank
                    FROM team
                    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @Rank:=0) Sub0
                    ORDER BY TeamPoints DESC
          ) Sub1
```

**UPDATE [PROBLEM SOLVED]**

I got the problem solved, below is the solution with reference to the user who solved it

You are just doing a SELECT statement. In order to UPDATE it really you have to use an UPDATE statement on the original table and use that query to feed values of teamRank:

```
UPDATE team t
INNER JOIN(
       SELECT TeamID,
       TeamPoints,
       @Rank := @Rank + 1 AS TeamRank
       FROM team
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT @Rank:=0) Sub0
       ORDER BY TeamPoints DESC
       ) a ON a.teamID = t.teamID
       SET t.teamRank = a.teamRank
```

User: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1385896/filipe-silva "

Thanks to Filipe Silva ..

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
UPDATE 
SELECT TeamID,
       TeamName,
       TeamLeader,
       TeamEmail,
       TeamWins,
       TeamLoss,
       TeamPoints,
       TeamRank
       FROM
          (
             SELECT TeamID,
                    TeamName,
                    TeamLeader,
                    TeamEmail,
                    TeamWins,
                    TeamLoss,
                    TeamPoints,
                    @Rank := @Rank + 1 AS TeamRank
                    FROM team
                    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @Rank:=0) Sub0
                    ORDER BY TeamPoints DESC
          ) Sub1
SET TeamRank=123
WHERE  TeamID =1
```

Comment: I dont understand whats the issue .. Error: Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\teamrankingdb\updated_rank.php on line 58

Comment: run the query in mysql directly if it works there is something wrong in your php code

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT TeamID, TeamName, TeamLeader, TeamEmail, ' at line 2

Comment: Same error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT TeamID, TeamName, TeamLeader, TeamEmail, ' at line 2

Answer (score 0):

```sql
UPDATE   team, (SELECT @Rank:=0) Sub0
SET      TeamRank = @Rank := @Rank + 1
ORDER BY TeamPoints DESC
```

Comment: Can you please edit it in the code, its giving me this error ..
Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\teamrankingdb\updated_rank.php on line 71

Comment: @ZainSohail: Inspect the value returned by [`mysqli_error($link)`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php).