# Updating Rank Row in table from PHP

Tags: php, mysql

This code create's rank on the fly and set's them accordingly.. Now the question is how do I update the Rank values in the table, without duplicating?I have posted this question recently but didn't find the solution.I am applying this code to a PHP code so that the rank updates with respect to TeamPoints ...

Help me Please! Thanks ...

```
SELECT TeamID,
   TeamName,
   TeamLeader,
   TeamEmail,
   TeamWins,
   TeamLoss,
   TeamPoints,
   TeamRank
   FROM
      (
         SELECT TeamID,
                TeamName,
                TeamLeader,
                TeamEmail,
                TeamWins,
                TeamLoss,
                TeamPoints,
                @Rank := @Rank + 1 AS TeamRank
                FROM team
                CROSS JOIN (SELECT @Rank:=0) Sub0
                ORDER BY TeamPoints DESC
      ) Sub1
```

Comment: I'm not sure i understand. You have a teamRank column in team table and you want to update it with the value you get from that quey?

Comment: Some of these questions lately that doesn't even make sense. At the very least put some thought behind your question.

Comment: Yes I want to update the TeamRank column but the issue is that this query is not updating the column TeamRank in the database.

Comment: Duplicate of [Updating Rank in table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20503914/updating-rank-in-table) (created by the same user)

Comment: `SELECT` **!=** `UPDATE`

Comment: @Nic I mentioned that is the Question ..

Comment: @AttisBarros I am new to MySQL thats why I get stuck at simple things, the solution is simple. I just cant figure out how to solve it ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just doing a `SELECT` statement. In order to `UPDATE` it really you have to use an `UPDATE` statement on the original table and use that query to feed values of teamRank:

```sql
UPDATE team t
INNER JOIN(
  SELECT TeamID,
  TeamPoints,
  @Rank := @Rank + 1 AS TeamRank
  FROM team
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @Rank:=0) Sub0
  ORDER BY TeamPoints DESC
  ) a ON a.teamID = t.teamID
SET t.teamRank = a.teamRank
```